TikZ animation attributes: reuse and parametrize
I want to make a somewhat complex animation. I have multiple groups of components that should appear and disappear at the same time within a group (but different groups have different timelines). I have read this section of the docs (about the :stage animation attribute). By trial and error I arrived at something similar to the following (simplified) example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,animations,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \foreach \t in {0, 1, ..., 5}{%
        \begin{subfigure}[p]{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}[
                animate={
                    1to3:stage = {
                        1s="true",3s="true"
                    },
                    2to4:stage = {
                        2s="true",4s="true"
                    },
                },
                make snapshot of = \t,
                ]
                \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (4,2);
                \node (A) at (0.5,1.5) {a};
                \node (B) at (1.5,1.5) {b};
                \node (C) at (2.5,1.5) {c};
                \node (D) at (3.5,1.5) {d};
                \node (a) at (0.5,0.5) (1to3) {$1-3$};
                \node (b) at (1.5,0.5) (1to3) {$1-3$};
                \node (c) at (2.5,0.5) (2to4) {$2-4$};
                \node (d) at (3.5,0.5) (2to4) {$2-4$};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{$t=\t$}
        \end{subfigure}
    } % end foreach
    \caption{Animation example.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


In case it matters, the document was compiled with LuaLateX. The manual says it should not matter for snapshots, though:

Since this computation is done by TikZ and since only “normal” graphics command are inserted into the output, snapshots work with all output formats.

The compilation log does not show any warnings, but there are two problems:

The (a) and (c) animations work correctly (appearing and disappearing at the prescribed times), but (b) and (d) are (incorrectly) always on. If I comment out the line for node (a), then (b) starts working correctly. I assume the code defining 1to3 is somehow consumed when applied to (a) and then it does not work for (b); is there a way to avoid it?
There is some code duplication in the definition of the stage-unstage animation. Ideally I would not define separately 1to3 and 2to4, but rather define one, parametrizable attribute, and call it with parameters; something like

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    animate={
        startstop:stage = {
            #1s="true",#2s="true"  % this (obviously) does not work
        },
    },
    make snapshot of = \t,
    ]
    % (snip...)
    \node (somenode) at (1.5,0.5) (startstop{1}{3}) {some text};
    % (snip...)
\end{tikzpicture}

For #2, initial research led me to suspect it is possible through appropriate pgfkes shenanigans, see in particular How to pass parameters to \tikzstyle? and the docs referenced there. (I did not achieve anything meaningful though.)

While the manual disapproves of using animate because of timelines (which apparently is only a problem if the same attribute of the object is animated more than once), in this simple case it seems to do just the right thing.
We define a startstop = <start> to <end> key which uses its two arguments to set up the stage times.
(I've took the liberty to align the upper nodes properly.)
Code
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,animations,positioning}
\tikzset{
  startstop/.style args={#1 to #2}{
    animate={myself:stage={#1s="true", #2="true"}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\foreach \t in {0, 1, ..., 5}{%
  \begin{subfigure}[p]{0.4\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[make snapshot of = \t]
  \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (4,2);
  \path[anchor=mid, nodes={yshift=-.35ex}]
   node[anchor=mid] (A) at (0.5,1.5) {a}
   node[anchor=mid] (B) at (1.5,1.5) {b}
   node[anchor=mid] (C) at (2.5,1.5) {c}
   node[anchor=mid] (D) at (3.5,1.5) {d};
  \node[startstop = 1 to 3] (a) at (0.5, 0.5) {$1-3$};
  \node[startstop = 1 to 3] (b) at (1.5, 0.5) {$1-3$};
  \node[startstop = 2 to 4] (c) at (2.5, 0.5) {$2-4$};
  \node[startstop = 2 to 4] (d) at (3.5, 0.5) {$2-4$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{$t=\t$}
  \end{subfigure}
} % end foreach
\caption{Animation example.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

Output

